# PHP Email on redirect

Tags: php, email

I have a page on my website that only certain users can access, and for that I made a check that looks into the MySQL database to see if they fulfill the requirements or not, and if they don't then it redirects them back to the dashboard. But in some cases it seems to be redirecting when it shouldn't, and I would like to send an email to myself with some variables when it does that, this is the code I have but it's not working for some reason,

```
    if (header('Location: '.bloginfo('home_url').'/profile')) {

    $to = "email@live.com";
    $subject = "View-vid error";
    $body = 'User ID: '.$user_ID. '  ID: '.$ID. '  Type: '.$Type;
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
```

I would also like to add the browser and operating system, if possible, to the body of the email.

Comment: Why would one want to do _that_? Why don't you just log that into a file (appending each incident) and that's it?

Comment: "but it's not working for some reason" is nothing we can help you with. What happens? What error do you get?

Comment: Hey, by it's not working, I mean it's not sending an email.

Comment: Read up on `get_browser` to get the details [Get Browser](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Comment: Again: "it's not working" does not help. I asked for an error message. What is in the http servers log files? What is in the mail servers log files?

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons why its not sending email, however, from my understanding header does not return a value of true/false [Header](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a great idea.  It makes more sense to write the information to the log.  Regardless, `header()` doesn't return anything so your if statement evaluates to false.

```
$isAllowed = // your check.
if (!$isAllowed) {
   header('Location: '.bloginfo('home_url').'/profile');
   $to = "email@live.com";
   $subject = "View-vid error";
   $body = 'User ID: '.$user_ID. '  ID: '.$ID. '  Type: '.$Type;
   mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
```

Comment: Lol, indeed, didn't spot that! Wow.